# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, objective-c-blocks

I've a method to sort out the NSManagedObjects using a key. The method looks like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)sortArrayDateWise:(NSMutableArray *)arr_msg withKey:(NSString *)str_key isAscending:(BOOL)isAscending andDateFormat:(NSString *)str_dateFormat {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [formatter setDateFormat:str_dateFormat];

    NSComparator compareDates = ^(id string1, id string2) {
        NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:string1];
        NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:string2];

        return [date1 compare:date2];
    };

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:str_key ascending:isAscending comparator:compareDates];

    [arr_msg sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDesc, nil]];

    return arr_msg;
}
```

Most of the time it works perfectly but sometimes there is an error like

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010**

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: "How can this issue be solved?" The first step would be to reproduce it in the debugger and tell us which line it breaks on.

Comment: @JeremyP It breaks on line [arr_msg sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDesc, nil]];

Comment: Hey.. were you able to solve this crash?